# What was Verdoni's first name?

Tags: history, famous-players

Did you know that Verdoni was known to be a chess champion in the 19th century, but what was his first name?

Comment: There is a rather long german wikipedia article about Verdoni, which says that his first name and date of birth are unknown.

Answer (score 2):

To expand BKFM's comment, [this article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdoni) says:

> Verdoni, dessen Vorname und Geburtsjahr unbekannt sind, soll
>   italienischer Herkunft gewesen sein. Sein schachliches Wirken vollzog
>   sich in Paris und später in London.

This translates loosely as " Verdoni, whose first name and date of birth are unknown, was of Italian stock. His chess career was in Paris and later London."